# Finding the exit node using tor browser

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration

so I've configured my torrc file to only use exit nodes in Russia. Now, I type in the URL of the website that I want to visit and the request is successful. Is there a configuration setting in the browser that will allow me to figure out the IP address of the exit node that was to process the request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

It can be viewed in the Tor Button display. Click the green onion button *(next to the address/search bar)* and you should see a panel at the side of the pull-down menu entitled *"Tor circuit for this site"*, which shows the circuit that is in use for connecting to the site.

The last one on the list before "Internet" is the exit node in use for the connection.